# How to set AWS RDS Parameter Group columns with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to set the below columns in AWS RDS' Parameter Group settings via Terraform
[image]

From the official Terraform docs, I see how to set `Name` and `Value`, but what about the other columns here like `Allowed values`, `Modifiable`, etc?

```
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "default" {
  name   = "rds-pg"
  family = "mysql5.6"


  parameter {
    name  = "character_set_client"
    value = "utf8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible! The values for `Allowed values` and `Modifiable` are set by AWS for all values within a parameter group, which controls, if you are allowed to modify and if yes, which values are possible.

In some **special cases**, you can ask the AWS support to adjust values for you, if you are not allowed to modify them by yourself.
This prevents you and also AWS to configure a setup of your database, which won't fit to your choosen instance (like in some cases the memory or maximum connections).

For terraform (or the API itself) it doesn't matter, if those values are modifiable or not. If it won't fit into the range of possible values or you are not allowed, the settings will still not be set without any errors reported to the output.